# how to check textbox isEmpty in angularJs Factory?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-ng-model

how to check textbox isEmpty in angularjs Factory?

My HTML Source is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="test">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: test === null or test===undefined or typeof test === "undefined"

Comment: Kindly give your solution in Full Script. How to Write a angularJS Factory and how Can I access the Factory in my TextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var customersCtrl = function($scope,Validate){

    var isEmpty = Validate.isEmpty($scope.test);

    $scope.Validation = Validate;
    if(isEmpty){
        console.info('Textbox is empty');
    }else{
        console.info('Textbox is not empty');
    }
};


angular.module('myApp').controller('customersCtrl', customersCtrl);

var Validate = function() {

    var factory = {};

    factory.isEmpty = function(val){
        var result = false;
        if(!val){
            result =  true;
        }

        return result;
    };


    return factory;


};



angular.module('myApp').factory('Validate', Validate);
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuVXSu5C5ZBrEZj1ZR8j?p=preview) according to your requirement.

Comment: How Can I bind this Validation Factory with OnChange Event of TextBox ?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan - Have a look at the updated answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('customersCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.changed = function(){
      if(!$scope.test){
        $scope.msg = 'empty';
      } else {
        $scope.msg = 'not empty';
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
   <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="changed()"/>
    {{ test }} | {{ msg }}
 </div>
```

Comment: I need a angularJS Factory Method to Validate the TextBox isEmpty.

Comment: Then create yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you can check the model value at any point in time. Like

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {

  if($scope.test == ""){
   // textbox is empty, do your stuff here
  }

});
```

Comment: I need a angularJS Factory Method to Validate the TextBox isEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

additional trick !

you can check it on angular expression . see this below to example !

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="test">
    <span ng-show="test.length == 0">
  is empty </span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

hope !

Comment: I need a angularJS Factory Method to Validate the TextBox isEmpty.

Comment: No not like this. Kindly visit the URL I pasted here, it contains a Factory Method as like this I need. http://jsfiddle.net/agrublev/QjVq3/